# How to animate a height change using javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition

I have this image that gets revealed when clicked, but i would like there to be a transition animation of 1s or so.

I don't want to use jQuery. A mobile friendly css solution would be great.

Any ideas?

```css
#cover {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
#image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover" id="cover">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/cats/" onclick="myFunction()" id="image" />
</div>
<script>
  var isOpen = false;

  function myFunction() {
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var cover = document.getElementById('cover');
    if (isOpen === false) {
      cover.setAttribute("style", "height:" + image.offsetHeight + "px");
      isOpen = true;
    } else if (isOpen !== false) {
      cover.setAttribute("style", "height:100px");
      isOpen = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I do not think Javascript allows animation by default, why don't you try using setTimeout to create that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `transition: height 1s` to have a one second animation:

```css
#cover {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s; 
  -moz-transition: height 1s; 
  -ms-transition: height 1s; 
  -o-transition: height 1s; 
  transition: height 1s;  
}
#image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;

}
```

```html
<div class="cover" id="cover">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/cats/" onclick="myFunction()" id="image" />
</div>
<script>
  var isOpen = false;

  function myFunction() {
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var cover = document.getElementById('cover');
    if (isOpen === false) {
      cover.setAttribute("style", "height:" + image.offsetHeight + "px");
      isOpen = true;
    } else if (isOpen !== false) {
      cover.setAttribute("style", "height:100px");
      isOpen = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, i was trying `transition: all 1s linear 1s;` but your works ok

Answer (score 1):

Theres a hacky way to do this without any JS at all. I used the max-height attribute, this way it could be used for images that does not have a fixed height.

```css
#cover {
    min-height:100px;
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    transition: all linear 1s;
}

#coverToggle:checked + #cover {
    max-height:500px;
}

label {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}

input {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:-100px;
    left:-100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="coverToggle" />
<div class="cover" id="cover">
    <label for="coverToggle"></label>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/cats/" id="image" />
</div>
```